# Installing Software with Missing Library - libusb1.0

Tags: linux, installation, path, libraries, cmake

I'm installing software called bladeRF using cmake. The following error happens:

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/user/local ../

CMake Error at host/libraries/libbladeRF/CMakeLists.txt:104 (message):
  No libbladeRF backends are enabled.  Please enable one or more backends.
```

So I tried adding some flags to cmake:

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/user/local -DENABLE_BACKEND_USB=ON -DENABLE_BACKEND_LIBUSB=ON  ../

CMake Error at host/libraries/libbladeRF/CMakeLists.txt:203 (message):
  libusb-1.0 not found.  This is required to use the libbladeRF libusb
  backend.  For binary releases, try setting LIBUSB_PATH.
```

Then, I searched for the path to libusb1.0 using:

```
$ dpkg -L libusb-1.0-0
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0/README
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0/copyright
/lib
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.so.0
```

So libusb is installed. I then added another flag to cmake:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/user/local -DENABLE_BACKEND_USB=ON -DENABLE_BACKEND_LIBUSB=ON  -LIBUSB_PATH=/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf ../

CMake Error at host/libraries/libbladeRF/CMakeLists.txt:203 (message):
  libusb-1.0 not found.  This is required to use the libbladeRF libusb
  backend.  For binary releases, try setting LIBUSB_PATH.
```

I even tried both of these:

```
export LIBUSB_PATH=/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

Those didn't work either. How do I help cmake find the path to libusb?

UPDATE: gcc -v seems to show that it is searching in /usr while libusb is installed in /lib. Is this on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically when building software, you need the *development* version of the libraries.

You want `libusb-1.0-0-dev` installed

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. My solution was to do the following:

```bash
sudo apt install libusb-1.0-0
sudo apt install libusb-1.0-0-dev
```

I then tried a few times but cmake wouldnt work, even though libusb was showing (`dpkg -L libusb-1.0-0 libusb1.0-0-dev`). Then I rebooted (`sudo reboot now`) and once I got logged back in went back to the bladeRF/host folder from the cloned repo and simply did a `mkdir build`, `cd build`, `cmake ..` and it worked. Good luck!